# What is $\mathbb{Q}(m)$?

Tags: soft-question, definition, homology-cohomology

I came across various definitions of cohomology groups (motivic, Deligne) written in the form

$$ H^n(X, \mathbb{Q}(m))$$

for some integer $m$ and an algebraic variety $X$. I am used to seeing the second item in the above notation as the ring of coefficients of the cohomology (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ in singular cohomology). So I was wondering what ring $\mathbb{Q}(m)$ is. But then I have found the definition

$$ A(m) := (2\pi i)^m A  \subseteq \mathbb{C}$$

for subrings $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. I am even more puzzled, because $A(m)$ is not a ring, only an abelian group. Can someone explain to me what is meant in general with $\mathbb{Q}(m), \mathbb{R}(m)$ and the like and whether they have anything to do with the coefficients of, for instance, singular cohomology?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(m)$ is not a ring for $m\neq 0$. In fact, we have products $\mathbb{Q}(m)\otimes\mathbb{Q}(n)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}(m+n)$, so in cohomology, the product will go $H^p(X,\mathbb{Q}(m))\otimes H^q(X,\mathbb{Q}(n))\to H^{p+q}(X,\mathbb{Q}(m+n))$. Now, these twisted coefficients all come from different cohomology theories (Hodge, motivic, Deligne...) you said it yourself. So you should first ask for a specific one, and study it...

Comment: @Roland You mean that $\mathbb{Q}(m)$ stands for different things depending on the cohomology theory? But it still is, in some sense, an abelian group of coefficients, right?

Comment: @Roland By the way, do you know any good reference for learning about one (or more) of these cohomology theories? The references I have found so far are quite advanced and do not really define them step by step, they just give an overview of them (because the main interest lies in other things and cohomology is just used as an instrument)

Comment: In the motivic case : $\mathbb{Q}(m)$ are not abelian group ! They are complexes, and they are not easy to defines, just have a look at a some motivic cohomology book. On the other hand, the case of Hodge theory is much simpler. They indeed are groups.

Comment: Well I don't know what are your background, nor why you are interested in. These are not completely unrelated, still there are a lot of difference from one to another. Just take any book on Hodge theory (there are plenty of them). For motivic cohomology, this is much harder, either take the original paper of Voevodsky, or the lectures notes on motivic cohomology by Mazza, Voevodsky, Weibel.

Comment: @Roland Ok, thanks for your advice!